# How to ignore error if source and target is same when using `FileUtils.mv` in ruby

Tags: ruby, fileutils

I want to shuffle thousands of files into many directories like this.

```
require 'fileutils'
files = Dir.glob("**/*.jpg")
files.shuffle!
((files.size/100)+1).times do |i|
  FileUtils.mkdir_p("%03d" % i)
  100.times{|j|
    begin
      FileUtils.mv(files[j+i*100],"%03d" % i)
    rescue ArgumentError
    end
    }
end
```

Sometimes source and target are same file.
To ignore the error I'm using `rescue ArgumentError`.

But I think it's bad way to use `Exception` like this.
Is there better way to do nothing when source and target are same?

Comment: please put trace error, i think you may use `unless` condition

Comment: You should check if file or folder with new name exists before moving http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-exists-3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
orig, dest = files[j+i*100], "%03d" % i
FileUtils.mv(orig, dest) unless File.basename(orig) == dest
```